# How to check variable returned from MySQL in bash?

Tags: bash, mysql

I need to run a stored procedure using MySQL from bash. The stored procedure returns a variable and I need to check the value of the variable in bash to display it accordingly. If I echo the variable directly, it displays the value correctly, but if I check the value using `if`, the `if` condition is never satisfied and I don’t get 'YES' displayed in the following case.

To make things simple, I simplified the bash file like this:

```
result=$(mysql -h localhost -u$MYSQL_USER -p$MYSQL_PASSWORD -s -e "set @myVarible = 'YES';select @myVarible" $MYSQL_DATABASE)

if [[ $result == 'YES' ]] ; then
    echo YES
fi
```

The output of `echo -n "$result" | od -ctx1` is

```
0000000   Y   E   S  \r
         59  45  53  0d
0000004
```

Comment: Add a `;` before `fi`.

Comment: Just so we’re clear: your `result=$(mysql …)` command works, and `echo $result` outputs `YES`, but the `if … fi` command doesn’t output anything? Does `echo $result` output `YES` or `'YES'`? What happens if you put `$result` in double quotes (e.g.,  `echo "$result"`)?

Comment: Thanks G-Man, yes, if ... fi command doesn't output anything. echo $result output YES. samething if put $result in double quotes.

Comment: worth noting, in result=$(mysql …), if I delete '-s', and echo $result will display ' YESarible' without the quotes

Comment: `if [[ $result =~ YES ]] ; then`

Comment: Post output of `echo -n "$result" | hexdump -C`.

Comment: thanks Cyrus. using `=~` does make a difference. output of `echo -n "$result" | hexdump -C` is `hexdump: command not found`. now I do can check something, but in my case, the 2 returned values are `Not Processed` and `Processed`, using `=~` won't tell the difference. now it is better, but still can't compare the exact values.

Comment: (1a) If you don’t have `hexdump`, you could use `od -ctx1`, `od -cx`, or `od -cb`. (1b) A comment is fine for saying that you don’t have a diagnostic tool (like `hexdump`), but, in general, if somebody asks you to post the output of a command, you should do it by [edit]ing the question. (2) What do you mean when you say, “using `=~` won’t tell the difference”? Have you tried `if [[ $result =~ Not ]]`?

Comment: @G-Man I tried using `od -ctx1` and get the output, and updated in question. by “using `=~`won’t tell the difference”, I meant it is not able to differentiate exactly 2 strings, like "yes" and "yes1". I tried `if [[ $result =~ Not ]]` and it worked. I just like to know if there's a way to exactly compare 2 strings returned from mysql in bash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your output from `echo -n "$result" | od -ctx1` shows that your `result` variable
is getting a carriage return stuck at the end. 
(This is shown as a `\r` and `0d` in the `od -ctx1` output.) 
As far as anybody is concerned, this is just another character,
and it doesn’t match `YES` any more than `YESK` or `YESS` would. 
Arguably the best solution to your problem is to change your `mysql` command
not to output the carriage return.  But I don’t know how to do that,
and I do know how to fix the result after you’ve gotten it into the shell.

After your `mysql` command, say

```
result="${result%$'\r'}"
```

The construct

```
${ variable_name % string }
```

(where spaces are added for clarity) expands to the value of the variable,
with the string removed from the end. 
For example, if `$vehicle` is `carriage`, then `${vehicle%riage}` is `car`.

```
$' string '
```

is the same as `'string'` (a quoted string)
except the string can contain escape sequences,
like `\t` for <kbd>Tab</kbd> and `\r` for carriage return. 
So, `${result%$'\r'}` is the value of `$result` with a carriage return removed from the end. 
You should now be able to test it with code like `[[ $result == 'YES' ]]`.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. the way you explain it is excellent, very impressive.

Comment: Does this answer work for you? If it does, please “accept” it by clicking on the check mark. ([What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://superuser.com/help/someone-answers))